# How to browse files stored on android SD memory?

Tags: android

I want to be able to browse the files using android application and get the path of selected files. How can i do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this section on [Data Storage in the Android Developer APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Lots of good information here on how you access the SD card. Browsing it would be an extension of accessing the card's data. (Get a listing of the files on the SD card, and then display them to the user.)

Answer (score 1):

Use standard java classes as `File.listFiles();`. View the files any way you like in an activity - in a ListView for example. You may also need the method from the [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDMS to browse the files inside Android application.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 2 options how to do it:

1. Write your own Activity which will do browsing task - it's not very difficult. You'd need to fetch `ListView` with file list returned by `File.listFiles();`
2. Use any `Intent` which supports File browsing/managing - simply by calling those Intent. E.g. like [this one](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/159)